# terraform x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: terraform, containers, x509

I'm using Terraform as a part of the DevOps pipeline tools and recently I have changed my PC then the terraform stop working, my Terraform runs inside a docker desktop container, the new PC has windows 11 and I can run the terraform from it without getting the certification problem, but the docker can't init the Terraform and I'm getting this error

```
terraform x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yim9v.png)

I have tried to copy past manual certificates from host to container but nothing help.

Comment: It seems you are missing the CA cert that signed the certificate of the `registry.terraform.io` from  the trust chain inside of the container. Which OS is the container running?

Comment: The container OS is Ubuntu 21.10

Comment: You should probably check if you have `GlobalSign Atlas` CA cert inside of the container. Maybe run the commands listed here: https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/security-trust-store. If you are building your own Docker image, you can add the steps from the URL to one of the `RUN` commands.

Comment: Solved by adding a certificate to container /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

Answer (score 1):

If you come to this Q&A while using the [vSphere Terraform Provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vsphere/latest/docs) and you already added your root CA certificate to your OS, make sure to also add all intermediate CA certificates to your OS. Normally, you do not do this as a client, but Terraform seems to need that. I did not find any docs that mention this explicitly, but you can derive it from [these docs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/enterprise/install/interactive/installer#ubuntu), that describe how you can setup a custom Terraform container, where they explicitly add intermediate CA certificates:

> ```bash
> FROM ubuntu:bionic
>
> # Install required software for Terraform Enterprise.
> RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && \
>     apt-get update && \
>     apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends awscli ca-certificates curl daemontools git-core iproute2 netcat-openbsd openssh-client psmisc redis-tools ssh sudo unzip wget
>
> # Include all necessary CA certificates.
> ADD example-root-ca.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
> ADD example-intermediate-ca.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
> RUN update-ca-certificates
> ```

Make sure that whenever you add certificates to your certificate store, you also merge them into your certificate store with `update-ca-certificates` (Debian/Ubuntu) or `update-ca-trust` (CentOS/RHEL).

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding a certificate to container /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt –

Comment: what certificate did you add to /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing how I did in my Gitlab pipeline. If you are doing changes in a resource deployed in kubernetes cluster using Gitlab CI/CD pipeline, define a CI/CD variable (I.e CERT_B64) in Gitlab and put the value. Then use below script in `before_script` in your terraform-deploy job.

```
terraform-deploy:
  extends:
    - .base-terraform
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $S3_ACCESS_KEY
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $S3_SECRET_KEY
    AWS_ENDPOINT_URL_S3: $S3_ENDPOINT
  before_script:
    - apk add --no-cache gettext ca-certificates
    - echo -n $CERT_B64 | base64 -d > /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ca.crt
    - cat /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ca.crt >> /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
    - update-ca-certificates
```

Check [Terraform runs failing with "x509: certificate signed by unknown authority" error](https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/360046090994-Terraform-runs-failing-with-x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority-error)  for detailed explaination.